# Anonymous Access Javascript get list items

Tags: list, powershell, anonymous-authentication

I have a site which is set up as anonymous access, i have 3 lists and have javascript that gets items from both lists. Due to the anonymous access the items are not being brought back.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question? Please provide code chunks or efforts you have done? Please check this link:https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer, just needed to uncheck the Require Use Remote Interfaces permission in authentication providers